# How do I delete columns from a matrix based on a list in R?

Tags: r

I have a very large matrix that looks like this:

```
        AGAG      AAGAA     AGTG     AGAT     AAGAT     AGTT       
1001    14691      0          0        0        0        5
1002    13        12          0       5831     20473     4
1003    0        5831      20473       0        0        0
1004    0        7936       7936      7936      0        0
1005    16066      0         0         24       2        2
```

There are >8000 columns. I need to delete many (~3000) of these columns by the column name. I have abbreviated the column names here (genome sequences). Obviously, I can't type that many individually.

I made a separate table that has the column names I want to delete. For example:

```
AGAG
AGTG
AGTT 
AGAT
```

I tried to use subset and %in% so far to no avail.

Comment: What is the meaning of the rows? Samples? Is this data the result of some sequencing experiment?

Comment: Rows are sample names. Yes, these are genomic sequences.

Comment: Don't you have a lot less samples than you have genomic sequences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example with the `iris` dataset:

```r
col_to_rm <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length")
col_to_keep <- setdiff(colnames(iris), col_to_rm )
iris[, col_to_keep]
```

`iris` is a dataframe, but it will work as well if you have a matrix.

You should be probably thinking whether that data structure (matrix) is the best to save your data: you've got very many columns...

Comment: I downloaded iris and ran this and it did not work. Also, I have no choice - I have to leave the data structure as a matrix for downstream processing.

Comment: You do not need to download `iris`. `iris` comes with R. I am not challenging  your choice of having a matrix, but perhaps it is more easy to handle your data if you transpose it (I am guessing you have a few samples...)

Comment: This example has typos for the iris dataset column names, but once I resolved that, and imported my csv file correctly (not as factors) it work great.  Thanks!

Comment: @BrianAiken: what typos?